# Excluding leading and trailing white space in captured group with ? for greediness?

Tags: regex, tcl

Would you please explain why this code does not generate what I was expecting? Why is the leading white space between the spans not excluded from the text and the trailing white space is excluded--`{ leading space}` instead of`{leading space}`? Or how do I exclude both the leading and trailing white space from the captured group?

```
set v {<span class='wj'> leading space </span> <span class='wj'> leading space </span> }
set vlist [regexp -all -inline -- {<span class='wj'>[[:space:]]*?(.+?)[[:space:]]*?</span>} $v]
# Result: {<span class='wj'> leading space </span>} { leading space} {<span class='wj'> leading space </span>} { leading space}
# Expectation/Goal: {<span class='wj'> leading space </span>} {leading space} {<span class='wj'> leading space </span>} {leading space}
```

If there is only one span it works without the `?`s after `[[:space:]]*`. For multiple spans, if `+?` is used instead of `*?` for the leading space, it works, unless there isn't a leading space which does not match at all; and I'm not certain all instances will have a leading space. Thus, I assume it has to do with greediness with a `*` but I don't understand it.

Thank you.

```
set v {<span class='wj'> leading space  </span>}
set vlist [regexp -all -inline -- {<span class='wj'>[[:space:]]*(.+?)[[:space:]]*</span>} $v]
# {<span class='wj'> leading space  </span>} {leading space}
```

Comment: It looks like you're working with XML or HTML? I'd really strongly suggest using a XML parser package like [TclXML](http://tclxml.sourceforge.net/tclxml.html) or [htmlparse](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/htmlparse/htmlparse.html) from tcllib.

Comment: I'd recommend [tDOM](http://www.tdom.org/index.html) for HTML and XML parsing, assuming you're not working with a ridiculously large document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixed greediness REs are deep voodoo due to the way Tcl's automata-theoretic RE engine works. I don't really understand it, and I've read that source code! (I think it's something to do with a particular automaton only being able to operate in either greedy or non-greedy mode, but I could be wrong.)

The trick to making things actually work is to keep to one mode and force things in other ways. I've replaced `[[:space:]]` with its shorthand form, `\s`, and `\S` is the complemented form (`[^[:space:]]`, but who wants to write all that?)

```
set vlist [regexp -all -inline -- {<span class='wj'>\s*?(\S.*?)\s*?</span>} $v]
```

With your sample input, that sets `vlist` to:

```html
{<span class='wj'> leading space </span>} {leading space} {<span class='wj'> leading space </span>} {leading space}
```

which is the thing you wanted.

---

Do ***not*** do general parsing of HTML or XML with regular expressions. Use a proper library designed for the task. But scraping stuff out of a particular page for a few days is fine; the insane churn on the web won't matter then.

If you were to use tDOM, for example, you'd do this sort of parsing with:

```
package require tdom

set doc [dom parse -html $inputDocument]; # NB: WHOLE document, not fragment
foreach item [$doc selectNodes {span[@class='wj']}] {  # Use XPath to get the bit you want
    # You have to manually trim leading and trailing whitespace
    puts [string trim [$item asText]]
}
```